# WCS request to German statistics portal to retrieve GeoTIFF

Tags: wcs, request, http

I have a problem regarding a WCS (Web Coverage Service) from the German statistics portal ([here](https://agraratlas.statistikportal.de/#)).

I want to retrieve the whole map for the topic "Produktionsrichtung".

After clicking on "OpenData" it tells me to make a request to https://www.wcs.nrw.de/stba/agraratlas.

I tried to make the request with Postman. I looked up the Documentation for WCS Version 1.0.0 [here](https://portal.ogc.org/files/05-076):

https://www.wcs.nrw.de/stba/agraratlas?REQUEST=getCoverage&SERVICE=WCS&VERSION=1.0.0&COVERAGE=K13b_Produktionsrichtung_2020&CRS=urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84&BBOX=5.44398161746876852,47.1303875027453429,15.6169481027651535,55.1452293571731005&WIDTH=100&HEIGHT=100&FORMAT=image/geotiff

But it only returns 404 Unknown Reason.

Comment: No need to request a bounding box if you want the whole coverage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just tried it in QGis which seems to work with a [URL](https://www.wcs.nrw.de/stba/agraratlas?SERVICE=WCS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetCoverage&FORMAT=GeoTIFF&COVERAGE=K13b_Produktionsrichtung_2020&BBOX=4030000,2680000,4680000,3560000&CRS=EPSG:3035&RESPONSE_CRS=EPSG:3035&WIDTH=130&HEIGHT=176) of:

```
https://www.wcs.nrw.de/stba/agraratlas?
SERVICE=WCS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetCoverage&FORMAT=GeoTIFF
&COVERAGE=K13b_Produktionsrichtung_2020
&BBOX=4030000,2680000,4680000,3560000&CRS=EPSG:3035
&RESPONSE_CRS=EPSG:3035&WIDTH=130&HEIGHT=176
```

The only difference I can see is the `FORMAT` and `SRS` but the [DescribeCoverage result](https://www.wcs.nrw.de/stba/agraratlas?VERSION=1.0.0&SERVICE=WCS&REQUEST=DescribeCoverage&VERSION=1.0.0&COVERAGE=K13b_Produktionsrichtung_2020) claims it can do EPSG:4326 too.

Comment: Changing 
RESPONSE_CRS to EPSG:4326
worked!